# Google charts Y-axis step

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I'm working on a project using google data visualization API  and I'm trying to show a chart illustrating the numbers of visits of users during the last week .
the problem is that this number is always an integer and greater or equal to 0 but on my chart the Y-axis show decimal numbers .
how can I configure the options array to get only integers ?

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the y-axis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to show only integers (no decimals) in chart API x/y-axis labels](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/4qCeUgE-OmU), user *asgallant* suggests this:

```
vAxis: {
    format: '#'
}
```

In that same thread, user [Daniel LaLiberte](https://plus.google.com/100631381223468223275/posts) says [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-visualization-api/4qCeUgE-OmU/j_qFpsV9BLcJ):

> If you specify a format of '#' you will only see only whole integer values.  But if a value that is rounded is not close to an integer, the tick will appear to be in the wrong position, or the label will be wrong for the tick.
>
> The Google Charts API assumes you want 5 gridlines in many cases, and depending on where your data values fall, 5 gridlines may not work out to give you integer tick values.
>
> The better thing to do is to turn on the variable number of gridlines feature by specifying:
>
> `gridlines: { count: -1}`
>
> Then it tries hard to give you nice round tick values.
>
> You can also specify exactly what tick values you want by using the 'ticks' option.
>
> `gridlines: { ticks: [ -4, -2, 0, 2, 4 ] }`

Finally, the official documentation: [Customizing Axes: Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats)